# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_55: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I use 2 LSTM multilayer stack with dense layer it's showing me an error.
Here is my code :

```
model.add(LSTM(5, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(5,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

```
batch_input_shape=(1,1,4)
```

It's showing me following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_57: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Comment: Add this in first layer `return_sequences = True`

Answer (score 2):

Your second LSTM admits input of shape `[batch_size, time_steps, features]`. The first LSTM yields outputs of shape `[batch_size, output_units]`, since the parameter `return_sequences` defaults to `False`.

You need to explicitly set `return_sequences = True` in your first LSTM to render the two recurrent layers compatible.